# Excel Left Find Last Hyphen

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data that may look like this **CSP1-MNL** or **CSP-CX-MNL**.
What I want is to get the first part of that code. (e.g. **CSP1**, **CSP-CX**).

I got the location by extracting the last 3 letters by using the formula **=RIGHT(Q13,3)**.

I just need to extract the first part but there is the problem that the code may have 1 or 2 hyphen.

What I expect is **CSP-CX** to be extracted from CSP-CX-MNL
but I just got **CSP**.

Comment: Have you searched on here? There are several examples of this that you could edit to meet your needs...

Comment: i have. but having multiple hyphen complicates it. i think it's never asked before

Comment: It has been, find() within find() is one possibility but you have to deal with the errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several examples here in SO with what you need. Also, you were kind of close using `RIGHT`, but you need a different approach.

According to your post, you want to extract always all chars except the last 4 ones (`-MNL`). So you just need a LEFT to extrat all except the last 4 chars.

Try something like: `=LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-4)`. It should work for you, or at least give you a starting point.

[image]

Comment: whoa. just what i need. 
i didn't think of it that way.
thanks.